# error: incompatible types: Context cannot be converted to ArrayList<dataModel>

Tags: java

I don't know what am I supposed to do, can somebody help me??

> error: incompatible types: Context cannot be converted to
> ArrayList
> adapter = new myAdapter(getApplicationContext());

can you help me to solve my problem ??

this is my MainActivity.java :

```
adapter = new myAdapter(getApplicationContext());
recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

here is myAdapter.java :

```
public class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapter.myHolder> {
    ArrayList<dataModel> dataHolder;
    Context context;

    public myAdapter(ArrayList<dataModel> dataHolder) {
        this.dataHolder = dataHolder;
        //this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what does `getApplicationContext()` return? It seems, it returns `Context`, but in your constructor you expect the parameter of type `ArrayList<dataModel>`.

Comment: but when I put Context in function myAdapter, another error was happened..

Comment: That's because you are already passing `Context`, but you are expecting `ArrayList<dataModel>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your `getApplicationContext()` method returns `Context`, but in your constructor you expect parameter of type `ArrayList<dataModel>`, that's why it throws exception. Now you have 2 options:

- keep your constructor, but pass different parameter

  ```
  adapter = new myAdapter(someArrayList);
  ```
- change constructor, so that it accepts `Context`

  ```
  public myAdapter(Context context) {
      this.dataHolder = new ArrayList<>();
      this.context = context;
  }
  ```